# Retrieving distinct documents from Solr

Tags: solr, distinct, solr4, distinct-values

I've had hard time explaining and finding what I need so please put your self in my shoes for a moment.

My requirement comes from a relational database background. I may be using Solr to do something it wasn't designed to do, or may be it can do what I need, I still need to confirm that. Hopefully you can assist me.

After indexing numerous documents into Solr. I need to retrieve distinct documents based on a filter. Just think about it as retrieving distinct rows while also applying a WHERE condition.

For example, in a relational database, I may have the following columns

```
(Country)  (City)     (Whatever)
 Egypt      Cairo      Hospitals
 Egypt      Alex       Schools
 Egypt      Mansoura   Hospitals
 Egypt      Cairo      Schools
```

If I perform this query: `SELECT DISTINCT Country, City FROM mytable`

I should get the following rows

```
(Country)  (City)
 Egypt      Alex
 Egypt      Mansoura
 Egypt      Cairo
```

Now after indexing the original table (`SELECT * FROM mytable`), how can I achieve the **SAME** output from Solr ? How can I retrieve **documents** by saying that I need these documents to be **distinct** based on some fields ? I will also need to apply a **not null** filter for a specific field.

I don't need statistics of any kind, I only need to get the documents.

I hope I was clear enough. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would be achievable with [field collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) by grouping by multiple fields, but unfortunately only one field is supported right now. There is an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2526), check it out.

Comment: Thank you for just answering the question, but backing it up with official links too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with facet?
You should do somethings like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&facet=on&facet.field=city&facet.field=country
```

he will return you all the city (with a distinct) and the his count.
[Here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters) there is the wiki if you want to learn more about it.

I hope this help you.

Comment: This returns the distinct values for each field separately. I need to retrieve distinct documents.

Answer (score 0):

Another good solution available from Solr 4 is based on [Pivot (Decision Tree) Faceting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Pivot_DecisionTree_Faceting).

Try with:

```
/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.pivot=Country,City
```

This should return:

```
  "facet_counts" : {
        "facet_queries" : {},
        "facet_fields" : {},
        "facet_dates" : {},
        "facet_ranges" : {},
        "facet_pivot" : {
           "Country,City" : [ {
                 "field" : "Country",
                 "value" : "Egypt",
                 "count" : 4,
                 "pivot" : [ {
                       "field" : "City",
                       "value" : "Cairo",
                       "count" : 2
                 }, {
                       "field" : "City",
                       "value" : "Alex",
                       "count" : 1
                 }, {
                       "field" : "City",
                       "value" : "Mansoura",
                       "count" : 1
              } ]
           } ]
        }
  }
```